# Designing a project in LaTeX on Overleaf effectively + LaTeX questions about titles

Tags: titles, overleaf, structure

I am currently working on a project using LaTeX on an online website called "Overleaf".

The thing is, I am only familiar with some LaTeX syntax, but not its design patterns. What I mean, is that I don't know how to construct a long article, should I write *everything* in one document? or open a new file (.tex) for each "section" (as I would like)? If yes, then will I be able to merge those together into one file at the end of the day?

[image]

Here is part of my "project", should I just write everything in one file or break down to pieces the whole document, just not to have a lot of text in only one .tex file?

Now a more technical question:

The first document that should come is Page-9.tex, it has this nice titles (my name, the date etc..) then what I want to do is only use "sub-titles" that will mention which page we are currently looking at (I am not talking about the latex pages, this is included automatically) - what I mean by that is my personal indexing of sub-titles ("Edition VI...").

This is for example, this kind of "sub-titles" I want in each page:

[image]

This works well on the first page, which includes this code

```
\title{Edition VI Answers}
\author{ABC}
\date{December 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction

\newpage

\title{Edition VI Answers - Page 9}
```

However when I try doing this on a blank page (page-11.tex) - it does not work..:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{Edition VI - Page 11}
\end{document}
```

Any idea why? again, I don't want big titles, I want small "section-like" titles.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are some nice tutorials on overleaf explaining how to structure large projects here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project and here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects

Comment: @DG' Thank you sir! I really appreciate it, I will take a look at these links.